# Ignore some conditions in 'case' statement

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a script which will get constraints automatically from system table in oracle, i just want primary key(P) and foreign key(R) and i have to ignore other constraints like C,U,V,O.

```
SELECT
    B.COLUMN_NAME,
    CASE
      WHEN A.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P' THEN ', PRIMARY KEY('||B.COLUMN_NAME||')'
      WHEN A.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' THEN ', FOREIGN KEY('||B.COLUMN_NAME||') 
      REFERENCES'||' '||(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM all_cons_columns WHERE OWNER 
      ='XXXXXXX' AND COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME AND CONSTRAINT_NAME != 
      A.CONSTRAINT_NAME) ||'('||B.COLUMN_NAME||')'
    ELSE ' '
    END AS CONSTRAINTS
    FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS A JOIN TABLE_SCRIPT2 B
    ON B.CONSTRAINT_NAME = A.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE OWNER= 'XXXXXXX' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'XXXXXXX'  )
```

When i run the script i got an output like this

```
   , PRIMARY KEY(XXXXXXX)














, FOREIGN KEY(XXXXXX) REFERENCES YYYYY(XXXXX)
```

for the other constraints i got spaces, if i remove the else condition i will get (null) instead of spaces, how to get only P,K without null or space.

Comment: You just need to add a predicate `and case ... end != ' '` (or, if you remove the `else ' '` bit from the case statement, `and case ... end is not null`).

Answer (score 1):

Add a below condition to WHERE caluse

```
A.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P','R')
```

Comment: I will try ,Thank you